# Help with Biconditional Constrapositive

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I am working on proving the following biconditional:

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers. Prove that $x^2\equiv y^2$ (mod 16) if and only if either (1) $x \equiv 0$ (mod 4) and $y \equiv 0$ (mod 4) or (2) $x \equiv 2$ (mod 4) and $y \equiv 2$ (mod 4).

My question is regarding the contrapositive of the result. Breaking the consequent into 4 statements I have:

$P$ : $x \equiv 0$ (mod 4); $Q$ : $y \equiv 0$ (mod 4); $R$ : $x \equiv 2$ (mod 4); and $S$ : $y \equiv 2$ (mod 4).

Thus, the consequent may be represented as $(P \land Q) \lor (R \land S)$. Using De Morgan's Laws, the negation may be represented as $(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (\lnot R \lor \lnot S)$

I thought the most straightforward way to prove this would be by cases, but it seems like that would entail many cases and subcases. For instance, assuming $\lnot P$ and $\lnot R$ would mean assuming that $x\not\equiv0$ (mod 4) and $x\not\equiv2$ (mod 4). Would I have to then prove $x^2\not\equiv y^2$ (mod 16) for $x, y$ where $x\equiv1$ (mod 4), $x\equiv3$ (mod 4), and $y\equiv i$ (mod 4) where  $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, and so on for the other three cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As $x+y+ x-y=2x$ or $x+y-(x-y)=?$ is even

So, here $x+y, x-y$ must be even

$\implies4$ divides  $$\dfrac{x+y}2\cdot\dfrac{x-y}2$$

**Case**$\#1:$ If $4\mid\dfrac{x-y}2\iff8|(x-y)$

**Case**$\#2:$ Similarly, if $4\mid\dfrac{x+y}2\iff8|(x+y)$

**Case**$\#3:$ If $2\mid\dfrac{x-y}2\iff4|(x-y)$ and $2\mid\dfrac{x+y}2\iff4|(x+y)$

Observe that in all cases, we need the sum of difference to divisible by $2,4$ or $8$

$x,y$ can safely be odd